# Order by Key and merge values of a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have Map like this :

```
Map<Date, List<T>> data = new HashMap<Date, List<T>>();
```

In a for loop the data is added in this data map.

Now I have to merge the Value column from entire Map to a single `List<T>`. The merging should happen in the ascending order based on Key which is Data.

I have written a foreach loop like this :

```
List<T> newData = new List<T>(); 
Iterator<Map.Entry<Date , List<T>>> itr = data.entrySet().iterator();
         
while(itr.hasNext())
{
     Map.Entry<date, List<T>> entry = itr.next();
     newData.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```

How can I make this order by Date (key) before adding to `newData` variable?

Comment: use `TreeMap` `Map<Date, List> data = new TreeMap<>()` , it sorts by keys when adding.

Comment: @ProGu , So if I directly create a TreeMap and add the values in it , I dont have sort it separately, is it ? Is there a way I can merge the Value column without running a while or foreach loop . If you can show me an example it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes - adding values to a TreeMap can be done in any order - it keeps its entries ordered. Technically, a TreeMap doesn't guarantee that it sorts its entries, it only guarantees that its will iterate over its entries in sort order.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with a stream pipeline, which would let you do both in one statement:

```
List<T> newData =  data.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByKey())
        .map(Entry::getValue)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Entry.comparingByKey()` will give a comparator that uses keys (your date objects) to sort the stream.

Please note that your `T` objects will be included in the resulting list based only on the `Date` key they correspond to, there will not be any sorting of `T` values in the resulting list (unless they were already sorted in all smaller lists initially added to the map).

Answer (score 0):

// If you have an existing "data" hashmap. Otherwise, you can directly add into TreeMap.

```
TreeMap<Date, List<T>> yourSortedMap = new TreeMap<>(data);
Iterator<Map.Entry<Date , List<T>>> itr = yourSortedMap.entrySet().iterator();
         
while(itr.hasNext())
{
     Map.Entry<date, List<T>> entry = itr.next();
     newData.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```